# How to pass selected value of select box in another component in angular

Tags: angular

can anybody tell How to pass selected  value of select box in another component   in angular

Thanks

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far, and your actual code...

Answer (score 1):

You can use EventEmitter:

https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

In this case you can subscribe the event in parent component.

If the components are not closely related to each other, you can use a shared service, which can be injected to each related component.